# A-Frame loading custom font in assets not working

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am using this build of aframe:
https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/c9817f2/dist/aframe-master.min.js

I have setup a scene in aframe and loaded it onto my webserver.
Via the "a-asset-item" i can load and display .objs .mp3 and images(.png)
with #id just fine.

The only thing that's not seeming to work are custom fonts made with hiero.
I converted a font into a .fnt and a .png(fontimage) and loaded it like so into the code:

```html
<a-assets>

        <a-asset-item id="akzidenz" src="assets/akzidenz.fnt"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="akzidenzimage" src="assets/akzidenz.png"></a-asset-item>
        
<a-assets>
```

Then I called the font in an  element like this.

```html
<a-text id="title" position="0 2 -2" side="double"
        font="#akzidenz"
        fontimage="#akzidenzimage"
        value="This is a Title">
      </a-text>
```

When I open up the page on my website this error is displayed in the javascript console:

```js
components:text:error Error loading font  #akzidenz

3browser.js:111 components:text:error Error: error parsing font malformed file -- no <pages> element
    at Object.callback (https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/c9817f2/dist/aframe-master.min.js:58:1408)
    at a (https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/c9817f2/dist/aframe-master.min.js:183:1112)
    at o (https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/c9817f2/dist/aframe-master.min.js:183:980)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t (https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/c9817f2/dist/aframe-master.min.js:183:401) 
3(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: error parsing font malformed file -- no <pages> element
    at Object.callback (browser.js:71)
    at a (index.js:62)
    at o (index.js:129)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t (index.js:68)
```

The text is not displayed.
Every other kind of file in assets works.
Before I made this, I started out writing examples in glitch and there i pasted the cdn-link directly into it. This worked out.

```js
<a-text id="title" position="0 2 -2" side="double"
        font="https://cdn.glitch.com/1eed6da6-c9da-46d7-bb30-b441a645ff43%2Fakzidenz.fnt?1512042049508"
        fontimage="https://cdn.glitch.com/1eed6da6-c9da-46d7-bb30-b441a645ff43%2Fakzidenz.png?1512042052757"
        value="This is a Title">
      </a-text>
```

I also tried embedding the direct link like http://www.example.com/.../assets/akzidenz.fnt
Then I got a permission error.

**Can anyone help me out with this issue?
Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't done it already, run a local server for your project. Even if you had everything alright it won't work without a running server, as assets may not be served properly. Follow [this instructions](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server) to start your dev server and view your project.

I did a little research and it seems (I'm not 100% sure) that for now you cannot preload your font in `a-assets`. A-Frame expects to load your font from XML format (or a string to parse) - by providing it the id of your resource it does't seem to get the data it needs. Here is the line that throws your error:

```
data = data.toString()
var xmlRoot = parseFromString(data)
var pageRoot = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName('pages')[0]
if (!pageRoot)
  throw new Error('malformed file -- no <pages> element')
```

If you pass it a directory (remember about local server) it will work correctly, as it will receive a string and then parse it to XML.

You can definately preload the `img`'s though, as stated [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/asset-management-system.html#sidebar).

My final working code:

```
<a-assets>
  <img id="akzidenzimg" src="/assets/akzidenz.png">
</a-assets>
<a-sky color="#CCC"></a-sky>
<a-text id="title" position="0 2 -2" side="double"
    font="/assets/akzidenz.fnt"
    fontimage="#akzidenzimg"
    value="This is a Title">
</a-text>
```

My folder structure:

```
.
+-- index.html
+-- assets
|   +--akzidenz.fnt
|   +--akzidenz.png
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you so much for the input! So the solution is actually the following: I tried using the path u put in ur working code in mine. But then the Website declined acces because of the structure of my webfolders. What I did was use "assets/akzidenz.fnt". The Font then displayed but with wonky forms. So I also embedded the fontImage not with assets but like this "assets/akzidenz.png".  Now it works perfectly fine!

Comment: Maybe you used #akzidenzimage instead of #akzidenzimg ? That's a minor change i seem to made from your code. I have it working exactly as it's here, I also provided my folder structure for you.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to this problem is very easy.
When you are running aframe on a webserver, directly embed the font and the image like so:

```html
<a-text id="title" position="0 2 -2" side="double"
    font="assets/akzidenz.fnt"
    fontimage="assets/akzidenz.png"
    value="This is a Title">
</a-text>
```

The font and the fontimage does not seem to work fine with the asset system.

Answer (score 0):

so for me, pre-loading `<a-assets>` didnt help, but what i tried and works was this:

1. i was already running a node service with aws s3, so i hosted my `.json` and `.png` fonts there, and created a `GET` call like `/get-fonts/custom-msdf.json`
2. your client FE just calls the font like this

```
<a-text
 position="0 0 0"
 font="http://localhost:8080/get-font/fonts/custom-msdf.json"
 negate="false"
 value="this is a sample text"
 color="black"
></a-text>
```

if you dive into the `.json` file, you can see that it already points to the `.png` file with this line:

```
"pages": [
    "custom.png"
  ],
```

so we dont need to call `font-image` in `<a-text>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a-assets>
  <img id="akzidenzimg" src="/assets/akzidenz.png">
</a-assets>
<a-sky color="#CCC"></a-sky>
<a-text id="title" position="0 2 -2" side="double"
    font="/assets/akzidenz.fnt"
    fontimage="#akzidenzimg"
    value="This is a Title">
</a-text>
```

I tried using above method, but got an error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/assets/custom-msdf.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app , chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

> new: problem has been solved
> Solution: Start local server

```
npm install -g http-server
// Go to the folder where the file is located
http-server .
```

If you are using powerShell, you need to allow this feature since the powerShell execution policy does not allow running default scripts.

All allowed:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Current window allowed:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

Reason: The resource is accesses is not the local path accessed through the `file:` protocol. But the `aframe` is converted into an http request and requests need local `fnt` file, so local server must be started.

Comment: If you're encountering the same issue, pleae upvote the question or just create a question entirel. Don't add your question as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this rule before.
But I've solved it. We need to start a local server through http-server. Then visit localhost:8080/filename.